# Flash and Google Drive SDK cannot talk to each other

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I need to create a flash web app connecting to Google Drive SDK to retrieve a public binary file but I am facing cross domain security issues.

I am able to do it in javascript using **cross-site xmlhttprequest** with CORS. In AS3,  a **crossdomain.xml** file is requested on *docs.google.com*. However the current settings don't let flash access the file.

The solution I have as of now is to get the data using javascript and send it to the swf using ExternalInterface.

Is there any **better solution** (proxy is not an option in my case)?

**Edit**: it seems that the ideal solution will be to grant access to authorization headers in https://docs.google.com/crossdomain.xml :

```
<cross-domain-policy>
     <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="Authorization">
      </allow-http-request-headers-from>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This change will give the same security rights to Flash API than Javascript.

Can the google drive sdk team comment on it?

Answer (score 0):

CORS works for most operations with the Google Drive API. As you rightly say, you can use the Google JavaScript Client and use ExternalInterface. I would probably prefer this solution right now depending on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution with ExternalInterface works well in term of authorization, it is however highly inefficient as I need to transfer binary data between javascript and flash. I think you should update your crossdomain.xml as it just give access to flash to what is already allowed for javascript. Nothing less, nothing more...

Comment: I just want to add that downloading file directly from Google Drive in Flash is an important requirement for the gaming and multimedia market. In my case, I am transfering 3D data and using ExternalInterface is a very ugly fallback...