# Flash AS3 - Google Drive implementation

Tags: actionscript-3, air, google-drive-api

Anyone come across a good example of using Google Drive to save/load files from an AS3/AIR app? I'm trying to load and modify audio files, backing it up to a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this project for integrating the Drive API to an AIR project:
https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-as3-api-client/

I've found this question related to yours, in which it is mentioned that the best way to interact between AS3 and the API should be through Google JavaScript Client and use ExternalInterface. You can find more information here:
[Flash and Google Drive SDK cannot talk to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550894/flash-and-google-drive-sdk-cannot-talk-to-each-other)